# Running py2exe with multiple versions of python installed

Tags: python, py2exe

I have both python 3.2 and python 2.7 installed.  I am trying to compile a file, but since the default program for opening .py files is 3.2, it gives me an error for not having py2exe installed when I run the program.  I tried setting the default program to python 2.7, but it won't work because the two versions have the same name.  I changed the name for python 2.7, but the program wouldn't run at all.  What do I do?

Comment: Py2exe doesn't support Python 3, so it shouldn't be a problem. How are you running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use absolute path to point to python interpreter executable.

`c:\python27\python.exe setup.py py2exe`

Or install `cx_Freeze`, which seems much better than py2exe except the lack of onefile capability.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure C:\Python27 is the in your Path environment variable, and that C:\Python33 isn't. But as Blender's comment mentions, you can't use py2exe with Python 3.x.

See [here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) for how to change your environment variables in Windows 7.